# Run code on creation of a PHP class instance?

Tags: php, class, object

I want code to run whenever I create a new object. For example, see this:

```
<?php

class Test {
echo 'Hello, World!';
}

$test = new Test;

?>
```

I want it to echo "Hello, World!" whenever I create a new instance of this object, without calling a function afterward. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should read about [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

```
<?php
class MyClass {
   public function __construct() {
      echo "This code is executed when class in instanciated.";
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
class Test {
 function __construct(){
    echo 'Hello, World!';
 }
}
```

Comment: To be fair, PHP4 is largely obsolete now.

Answer (score 2):

Or on PHP 4 use:

```
class Test {
    function Test {
        echo 'Hi';
    }
}
```

Edit: This also works on PHP 5, so this is the best way to do it.

Comment: I think __construct() is the better way, because it doesn't work in PHP4.  :-)